# I need to add a space between the cell created dynamically swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

This is my structure where inside I have downloaded a Json from url

```
    var bikes = [BikeStats]()
```

this is my declaration about the table view

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

this is my code to crate the table view with n. rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return bikes.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    let imgURL = NSURL(string: "my_url/\(bikes[indexPath.row].Immagine)")
    if imgURL != nil{
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)?.renderResizedImage(newWidth: 70)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(bikes[indexPath.row].StatoBici.uppercased())"
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? BikeDetailViewController {
        destination.bike = bikes[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]  
    }
}
```

I need to add a space between the cell created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want blank rows between cells you need to increase the number of rows and configure alternating cells to be blank instead of filled with content.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return bikes.count * 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    // affect only the even numbered cells (0, 2, 4, 6, 8 etc.)
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.imageView?.image = nil
        cell.textLabel?.text = ""
        // set the colors to whatever you want
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        return cell
    }

    let dataIndex = indexPath.row / 2 // we need to do this because we're doubling the number of rows

    let imgURL = NSURL(string: "my_url/\(bikes[dataIndex].Immagine)")
    if imgURL != nil{
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)?.renderResizedImage(newWidth: 70)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(bikes[dataIndex].StatoBici.uppercased())"
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Note that using this logic will make the first cell empty too

Comment: your code does't work. I don't know why.  May you check if it's correct please?

Comment: There was a typo on the modulo line. It's fixed in the updated version.

Comment: i'ms so sorry but I have this error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Comment: A-ha! Sorry about that. Yes, because we're doubling the number of rows, we need to change how bikes data is accessed. To do that, we divide the `indexPath.row` by 2 to get the index of the data we want to actually use. I've updated the sample code with this fix.

Comment: Using this method, where ever you reference `bikes[indexPath.row]` you'll need to actually use `bikes[indexPath.row / 2]`

Answer (score 0):

To add spacing between UITableViewCell you can do it like so.

```
// Inside UITableViewCell subclass
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10))
  // for only bottom use UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0)
}
```

Edit:- in your code

```
class myCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame,  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0))
    }
}
```

then in tableView: `cellForRowAt indexPath` use the cell like so

```
let cell = myCustomCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
```

Comment: I don't have UITableViewCell, I create by code my cell.

Comment: you need to use custom cell to access the tableViewCell `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using sections in your tableView, i would recommend using this aproach

```
extension SomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return bikes.count
}
}

extension SomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> 
UIView? {
    return UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableview.frame.width, height: 10))
}
}
```